# Ordering a list of strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I want to order some simple list of strings, such as

```
name = {"1.62-s", "1.6-s", "1.63-s", "1.75-s", "1.70-s"}
name//TableForm
1.62-s
1.63-s
1.6-s
1.70-s
1.75-s
```

However, because of the following letter "-s" I cannot order the list. Any good way to order this instead of doing by manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
order = Ordering @ ToExpression[First @ StringSplit[#, "-"] & /@ name]
```

> {2, 1, 3, 5, 4}

```
name[[order]]
```

> {"1.6-s", "1.62-s", "1.63-s", "1.70-s", "1.75-s"}

---

**EDIT:** I changed `StringSplit` into `First @ StringSplit` due to important comments of george2079: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127637/ordering-a-list-of-strings/127643?noredirect=1#comment345226_127648), [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127637/ordering-a-list-of-strings/127643?noredirect=1#comment345240_127643), [(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127637/ordering-a-list-of-strings/127643?noredirect=1#comment345245_127643) below.

Comment: THank you so much! I end of using your code for the project!

Comment: watch, this has the same issue I noted under Bob's answer. You are applying `ToExpression` to the "s", so there could be unexpected results if `s` is a defined symbol.   ( you could do `First@StringSplit[#, "-"]` to fix that )

Comment: @george2079 Yes, now I see it. But do you have in mind any situation that this will actually fail? Nevertheless, `First@stringSplit` is ofc better.

Comment: as an example do `s := Pause[1]` and you'll see your sort take 5 seconds. Even though that scenaro might seem unlikely its the sort of thing that's hard to track down if it causes a problem.

Answer (score 6):

this sorts by numeric value:

```
SortBy[name, 
 ToExpression@StringCases[#, n : NumberString ~~ ___ :> n] &]
```

> {"1.6-s", "1.62-s", "1.63-s", "1.70-s", "1.75-s"}

note in some cases the numeric sorting is different from the string sort:

```
name = {"16.2-s", "1.6-s", "1.63-s", "1.75-s", "1.70-s"};
SortBy[name, StringTake[#, {1, -3}] &]
```

> {"1.6-s", "16.2-s", "1.63-s", "1.70-s", "1.75-s"}

```
SortBy[name, 
 ToExpression@StringCases[#, n : NumberString ~~ ___ :> n] &]
```

> {"1.6-s", "1.63-s", "1.70-s", "1.75-s", "16.2-s"}

Comment: Thank you for the code, even though I used @Corey's code, your code help me to understand more. I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
SortBy[name, StringTake[#, {1, -3}] &]
```

Comment: As @george2079 points out, you may want to add `ToExpression@` into the mix (before `StringTake`) to make the numerical sorting a little more robust. I was being lazy.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! This was the what I wanted, but there were some generalized answer for any case, so I did not accept yours. However, I appreciate for your code!

Answer (score 5):

```
name = {"1.62-s", "1.6-s", "1.63-s", "1.75-s", "1.70-s"};

SortBy[name, ToExpression]

(*  {"1.6-s", "1.62-s", "1.63-s", "1.70-s", "1.75-s"}  *)
```

Comment: watch for unexpected side effects should you happen to have a defined symbol "s" ..

Comment: Thank you, I think your code is the neatest one, but I used @Corey code for the project. Thank you anyway :D